# What features are in zsh and missing from bash, or vice versa?

Tags: bash, zsh

As a Linux user, I've always just used bash because it was the default on every distro I used. People using other Unix systems such as BSD seem to use other shells far more frequently. In the interests of learning a bit more, I've decided to try out zsh.

As a bash user:

- What features will I miss?
- And what ones should I look out for?

Comment: Similar questions on other SE sites:
[Worth switching to zsh for casual use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321)
[What's in your .zshrc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171563)
[What zsh features do you use?](http://superuser.com/questions/2127)
[Unique Features of bash compared to zsh](http://serverfault.com/questions/4993)
[Is there any reason to use bash over zsh?](http://serverfault.com/questions/93388)
[Moving from bash to zsh](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1577)

Comment: @Gilles someday it might be nice to have all those moved here... and merged

Comment: Also http://askubuntu.com/questions/1577/moving-from-bash-to-zsh

Answer (score 49, accepted):

*For a more extensive answer, read https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh/361957#361957*

There's already been quite a bit of activity on the topic on other Stack Exchange sites. My experience of switching from bash to zsh, as far as can remember (it was years ago²), is that I didn't miss a single thing. I gained a lot; here are what I think are the simple zsh-specific features that I use most:

- <sub>The zsh feature I most miss when I occasionally use bash is autocd: in zsh, executing a directory means changing to it, provided you turn on the `autocd` option.⁴</sub>
- Another very useful feature is the fancy globbing. The <strike>hieroglyphs</strike>characters are a bit hard to remember but extremely convenient (as in, it's often faster to look them up than to write the equivalent `find` command). A few of the simpler examples:
      `foo*~*.bak` = all matches for `foo*` except those matching `*.bak`
      `foo*(.)` = only regular files matching `foo*`
      `foo*(/)` = only directories matching `foo*`
      `foo*(-@)` = only dangling symbolic links matching `foo*`
      `foo*(om[1,10])` = the 10 most recent files matching `foo*`
      `foo*(Lm+1)` = only files of size > 1MB
      <sub>`dir/**/foo*` = `foo*` in the directory `dir` and all its subdirectories, recursively⁴</sub>
- For fancy renames, the `zmv` builtin can be handy. For example, to copy every `file` to `file.bak`: `zmv -C '(*)(#q.)' '$1.bak'`
- Both bash and zsh have a decent completion system that needs to be turned on explicitly (`. /etc/bash_completion` or `autoload -U compinit; compinit`). Zsh's is much more configurable and generally fancier.

If you run zsh without a `.zshrc`, it starts an interactive menu that lets you choose configuration options. (Some distributions may disable this; in that case, run `autoload zsh-newuser-install; zsh-newuser-install`.) I recommend enabling the recommended history options, turning on (“new-style”) completion, and turning on the “common shell options” except `beep`. Later, configure more options as you discover them.

²<sub>At the time programmable completion was zsh's killer feature, but bash acquired it soon after.</sub>
⁴<sub>Features that bash acquired only in version 4 (so were not widely available at the time this answer was posted, and are not available on the system-provided bash on macOS) are in smaller type.</sub>

Comment: Bash 4.0 now supports the `autocd` feature you discuss above. Enable the feature using the command `shopt -s autocd`. Then the feature works as you've described.

Comment: zsh also has the built-in `where` command, not to be confused with the `which` command.

Comment: @EdGrimm I think GNU and FreeBSD find can do everything zsh glob qualifiers can do (with `-exec` of a shell for things like selection with `e` and a pipeline into tools like `sort` and `sed` for rewriting with `e` and sorting). A lot more verbosely, of course.

Comment: After checking and rechecking the find manpage for more than a decade, I guess I stopped really looking. But if I'd have checked one last time before commenting, I'd have at least seen the -size option now takes units down to bytes.

Answer (score 12):

`zsh` lets you edit a multi-line command (see [zsh line editor](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_14.html#SEC45)), bash doesn't. If you try the same trick (`Ctrl-p`), bash fetches the last command.

Comment: Bash does this, at least as of version 4.2.37; it replaces newlines by semicolons and gives you a single line to edit.

Comment: Still not as nice. (:

Answer (score 12):

Also the default tab completion is better than bash... for example...

`~/.e.d`TAB will expand to `~/.emacs.d/` in zsh, bash will just beep.

Comment: it didn't. what non-default `setopt` option do you use for that (if any) ?

Comment: I realized that I have `_-.` set as a wildcard.  `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7906078/311660

Comment: If you can get completion to use fsf , then it can do that!
BUt I am finiding the current bash completion very difficult to hook in persoanl replacements for the system installed stuff... Especially for hostname expansion when you have a better methed that 'ssh known hosts' for the host list.

Answer (score 10):

Bash has the feature of being able to open ports using

```
/dev/tcp/host/port
```

or

```
/dev/udp/host/port
```

However, it is disabled in Debian as it is seen as a hindrance (if the path actually exists) and outside the scope of what a shell should do. [More information](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2006/11/msg00801.html) [debian mailing list]

Comment: zsh has the ztcp builtin though which has more capabilities than bash's /dev/tcp, doesn't have /dev/udp. I would rather use socat though.

Answer (score 4):

#### Which - enhanced in zsh

The `which` command in bash only reveals the location of a command.

In Zsh `which` will reveal the definition of an `alias`, the source for a `function` and the location of a command.

Let's say we had a shell alias:

```
alias gg='git log'
```

In Bash if we asked: `which gg` the result would be void

In Zsh: `which gg` will give us...

```
gg: aliased to git log
```

Let's say we had a shell function:

```
hello() {
    echo "Hello World"
}
```

In Bash if we asked: `which hello` the result would be void.

In Zsh: `which hello` will give us...

```
hello() {
    echo "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: Bash provides the same functionality via the `type` (builtin) command. And just to nitpick: `which` is an external command, not a bash builtin.

Comment: Relevant canonical question: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22812)

Answer (score 2):

## zsh - a complete shell

there are many, reading through [`zshcontrib(1)`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/extra/zsh/zshcontrib.1.en) one can detect two versions of `autoload`-able `tetris` games (the other with `ncurses`) in `zsh` in competition with `emacs`, for completeness (as described).

### =

I'd like to mention the `=` keyword, which can cause irritation with `curl` (URL's usually have `?var=val` in them; but it is `unsetopt`-able, I think):

- `q file =less` (`gentoo`) resolves to `q file $(which less)`

`=` expands to the full path of the command in question.

### other goodies

other things, out of the mind, are the right prompt `RPS1=%d` (to display `$PWD` in style), <kbd>Alt + H</kbd> (`run-help` ie. `man`), <kbd>Alt + ?</kbd>  (`which-command`), `vared`, and `zed` (`autoload` function), Emacs' minibuffer-like <kbd>Alt + X</kbd> to execute widgets without binding them, global and suffix aliases, extended history tracking command completion duration, `-m` and `-regex` matchers, shell emulation (eg. `csh`, `ksh` with `emulate`) and `autoload` `run-help` with file snippets for the built-ins.

### lamentations

I think most, if not all, of the features were implemented a long time ago, and reading through changelogs, there is no major changes and new feature additions, which is very sad (nothing to explore and discover anymore).

`bash` seem to be more *distributed* in `readline` (as opposed to `zle`) and `gnu history` in the linux spirit; e.g readline functions and keybindings can be applied globally (as kept in `~/.inputrc` and `/etc/inputrc`) if not overriden by bash-specific `bind`.

### conclusion

I personally think `emacs` (esp. from the prospect of (the current?) `emacs-nox` flavor) being the inspiration for the exceptional software like `zsh` and `tmux` did a very good job in being an example in such an implementation; for the people appreciating its worth (to the level of not needing/depending on `X` server). Unix shell is powerful enough, and its continuity and consistency is sufficient for a proper workflow and productivity (in overall computing).