# What are the significant differences between different shells?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ksh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the fundamental differences between the mainstream *NIX shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-the-mainstream-nix-shells)

If I write a shell script in `bash`, will it run in `ksh` as well?

if not, what are the differences?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-the-mainstream-nix-shells

Comment: The **Korn** shell is `ksh`. `csh` is the C shell. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on which specific commands/features you are using but generally no.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells for a summary of differences between shells.

Answer (score 3):

No. Both bash and ksh have custom specific extensions and behavior. If you want to write portable scripts, stick to POSIX syntax:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Answer (score 2):

It's best to treat each separate shell as a separate programming language. Don't try to write [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29) shell scripts, it makes them unreadable and clunky. Instead, learn how to program in one shell and then be careful with always specify that shell as the script's interpreter in the [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) on the first line.

Remember that the shell that your script is running in has nothing to do with the shell you're executing it from. Hence, you might be interacting with your UNIX system through `csh` while at the same time be writing all your shell scripts for `ksh`.

Comment: Slightly surprised about the down-vote. Please explain?