# What is the main problem someone migrating from bash to zsh should face?

Tags: bash, zsh

A few times I have had problems in bash that other using zsh didn't have and they were gloating about how smart they are.
Also I have seen zsh users among people that I admire, and I have tried a couple of times half heartedly to move to zsh but every time returned because I didn't have time (and was lazy) to learn to do my routine jobs in zsh.
Is there a good practical migration tool around? or are there some important things you would recommend that I learn to make the transition easier, at least so that I can try it and see if it makes any difference "for me"?
by the way I spend most of my life on mac, ubuntu and RedHat variants.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What features are in zsh and missing from bash, or vice versa?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/983/what-features-are-in-zsh-and-missing-from-bash-or-vice-versa)

Comment: @Gilles, it's similar, but I think it's sufficiently different.  I wouldn't call them duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While they are similar (more similar than Bash and Tcsh, for example) they are different enough to force you to read documentation before doing nontrivial configuration.

It is not hard at all to start using it though, just grab [someone's .zshrc](http://dotfiles.org/.zshrc) and modify it to suit your taste.

Additional reading:

- http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html
- http://zshwiki.org/

Comment: +2 for the zsh-lovers

Answer (score 2):

They are quite similar. In fact, I have [parallel configurations](https://github.com/mika-fischer/dotfiles) for bash and zsh so they behave quite similarly.

I found zsh to be not very hard to get into coming from bash. I think your question is quite broad and difficult to answer and to further help you we would need to know what exactly the issues are that you're facing.

In general, I'd recommend to give zsh a try, and come back with any issues you might have. I haven't regretted switching to zsh, it really does have many nice little features that make life on the command prompt much more pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

I did recently a transition because of some features. I don't use the terminal that much but I noticed that the autcomplete and the history works different.