# How to install Bash on FreeBSD?

Tags: bash, freebsd, software-installation

I really find that using `bash` helps a lot, when you need to retrieve strings of text that you used previously.

But how can I install it on FreeBSD?

I have tried typing `bash` into the terminal, but that returns the error: `bash: not found`

Comment: If you're going to switch shells, you might as well switch to zsh. [What features are in zsh and missing from bash, or vice versa?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/983)

Comment: I recommend looking at the [FreeBSD handbook](www.freebsd.org/handbook/) for this kind of questions. [Installing Applications: Packages and Ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have the ports tree installed, it's as easy as

```
cd /usr/ports/shells/bash
make all install clean
```

If you don't have the ports tree, just do this:

```
portsnap fetch extract
```

and then try again. You'll need to periodically update the ports tree:

```
portsnap fetch update
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by sr_ in a comment, FreeBSD also offers precompiled binary packages of many (most, but not all) ports. In practice, while they usually offer a faster install, I find the `pkg_*` tools don't handle installing dependencies as well as the ports system, so it can sometimes take a few goes to get everything working. However, it's well worth looking at `pkg_add` and friends.

There is a new poject under way, called [pkgng](http://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng/), which aims to address the problems with the current `pkg_*` tools. It's still fairly new, but it looks good.

Comment: Thank you, I have just tried that now, and I do need the ports tree - which is currently "fetching".

Comment: There're also binary packages, i.e. `pkg_add -r bash` should suffice... ([see this for more (maybe slightly dated) information](http://onlamp.com/bsd/2005/01/13/FreeBSD_Basics.html))

Comment: @sr_ - good point. My first recourse is always to ports, so I seldom even think about precompiled packages.

Comment: To make this bash binary your default shell run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash` as the user you want to change the shell for.

Comment: This also works for `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it is enough to just install the binary package:

```
pkg install bash
```

The `pkg_*` family of tools is deprecated and no longer present on any supported FreeBSD release.

If you don't have a good reason, there is no need to build Bash from ports.