# FreeBSD, bootstrapping pkg, "pkg-static: sqlite error while executing INSERT OR ROLLBACK INTO pkg_search"

Tags: freebsd, pkg

I was trying to install bash on a FreeBSD 10.2 system, see [How to Install bash on FreeBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43475/how-to-install-bash-on-freebsd)

But the install failed because pkg was trying to fetch from a too-new repository.

I then tried following the recipe at https://glasz.org/sheeplog/2017/02/freebsd-usrlocalliblibpkgso3-undefined-symbol-utimensat.html, which several sources said was the right thing to do.

However, part of the recipe involved uninstalling pkg and reinstalling it. That resulted in the following:

```
# pkg install -y pkg
The package management tool is not yet installed on your system.
Do you want to fetch and install it now? [y/N]: y

Bootstrapping pkg from 
pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:10:amd64/release_2, please 
wait...
Verifying signature with trusted certificate 
pkg.freebsd.org.2013102301... done
pkg-static: warning: database version 34 is newer than libpkg(3) 
version 31, but still compatible
pkg-static: sqlite error while executing INSERT OR ROLLBACK INTO 
pkg_search(id, name, origin) VALUES (?1, ?2 || '-' || ?3, ?4); in 
file pkgdb.c:1542: no such table: pkg_search
```

And so now I'm stuck. Can anybody tell me how I might recover from this state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try removing everything in `/var/db/pkg/` directory, but the proper solution is to upgrade to supported FreeBSD release (10.4 or 11.2)

Comment: Thanks; I'll give it a shot. I don't know if I can justify upgrading a system that I'm not even the owner of (just helping administer it), just to run one lousy bash script.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar symptom (line breaks added for readability):

```
# pkg info
pkg: Warning: Major OS version upgrade detected.  \
        Running "pkg-static install -f pkg" recommended
pkg: warning: database version 34 is newer than libpkg(3) version 33, \
        but still compatible
pkg: sqlite error while executing INSERT OR ROLLBACK INTO pkg_search(id, name, origin) \
        VALUES (?1, ?2 || '-' || ?3, ?4); in file pkgdb.c:1544: \
        no such table: pkg_search
```

I focused on this part of the error message:

```
no such table: pkg_search
```

and in my specific case, I was able to resolve my problem by doing:

```
# cp -p /var/db/pkg/local.sqlite /var/db/pkg/local.sqlite.safety
# sqlite3 /var/db/pkg/local.sqlite
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE pkg_search USING fts4(id, name, origin);
sqlite> .quit
```

That particular SQL query is mentioned in [this thread](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2017-January/106800.html) from January 2017.

After that SQL incantation, `pkg` became functional again and I was able to upgrade to the latest version of `pkg` and then upgrade or reinstall the rest of the packages.  This had been a 10.x to 12.x migration, so after upgrading `pkg` I did `pkg upgrade -f` on everything, and wound up with no more warnings or `sqlite3` errors:

```
# pkg -N; pkg info; pkg upgrade
pkg: 15 packages installed
apache24-2.4.41                Version 2.4.x of Apache web server
apr-1.7.0.1.6.1                Apache Portability Library
bash-5.0.7                     GNU Project's Bourne Again SHell
db5-5.3.28_7                   Oracle Berkeley DB, revision 5.3
expat-2.2.6_1                  XML 1.0 parser written in C
gdbm-1.18.1_1                  GNU database manager
gettext-runtime-0.20.1         GNU gettext runtime libraries and programs
indexinfo-0.3.1                Utility to regenerate the GNU info page index
libnghttp2-1.39.2              HTTP/2.0 C Library
libxml2-2.9.9                  XML parser library for GNOME
linux_base-f10-10_10           Base set of packages needed in Linux mode for i386/amd64 (Linux Fedora 10)
pcre-8.43_2                    Perl Compatible Regular Expressions library
perl5-5.30.0                   Practical Extraction and Report Language
pkg-1.11.1                     Package manager
readline-8.0.0                 Library for editing command lines as they are typed
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
Checking for upgrades (0 candidates): 100%
Processing candidates (0 candidates): 100%
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Your packages are up to date.
```