# Time all executions in bash

Tags: bash, time, profiling

Is there a way to run *all* commands in `bash` as if they were invoked with `time` in front? I want that I could type `$ some_command` and this will actually invoke `$ time some_command`.

Comment: Not very well http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command. Perhaps zsh…

Comment: zsh with the [grml zsh config](http://grml.org/zsh/) does this by default. It shows the time only if it exceeds a certain value.

Comment: @jofel. Actually, with `zsh`, it's just a matter of `REPORTTIME=0` (report time of those processes that take more than 0 seconds).

Comment: I am looking for an answer using `bash`. I don't think I'll change my shell just because of this feature.

Comment: There are [other reasons](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/983/what-features-are-in-zsh-and-missing-from-bash-or-vice-versa) to change your shell.

Answer (score 0):

Itself `time command` do it :

```
time ls
time gimp
```

But if you want to invoke `time` for each `command`, you can customize a script for yourself, 
you should run everything with it but it's not good way.

Comment: My question is exactly how this script should look like... It would be really nice to be able to turn on and off this script.

Comment: I think Stephane Chazelas answer better than me...