# Search for a previous command with the same prefix when I press Up at a shell prompt

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, command-history, tcsh

Coming from a FreeBSD world I wish to make the Linux terminal behave like FreeBSD one, especially the 9.1 version, basically when you type `cd` in the terminal and push the "up" arrow you can browse all the commands in the history starting with `cd` which makes you gain a lot time.

I don't know how to enable this feature in Linux Debian or CentOS which force me to type the whole, could someone please help.

Comment: That's a function of the shell, not the terminal.  What shell are you using in FreeBSD?  You may be able to get the same (or similar) shell for Linux.

Comment: I am using the tcsh shell.

Comment: I'm using tcsh under OS X and didn't have this handy-looking behavior… After some searching, I found I could enable it by putting `bindkey -k (up|down) history-search-(back|for)ward` in my `.tcshrc` [as described here](http://howto.unixdev.net/tcshrc.html#34). Cool!

Comment: Other answers tackle it, but if you want more, take a look at https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search Prezto (https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) is also full of zsh goodies.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add to the following to `~/.inputrc`:

```
# Press up-arrow for previous matching command
"\e[A":history-search-backward
# Press down-arrow for next matching command
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

**Explanation**

`~/.inputrc` is the configuration file for [GNU readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline). Many shells, including `bash` and `tcsh` use readline for command line editing. The two lines above will tell readline to invoke its history search functionality when the escape sequences for the up-arrow key (`\e[A`) and down-arrow key (`\e[B`) are encountered.

Comment: I like to [add F12](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/etc/inputrc#L44) to put last word of the last line onto end of current command.`Last word` is often a _path_ which I want try out in various arcane clichés. And [Shift F12](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/etc/inputrc#L44) to put me back editting the whole last line from the start. `~/.inputrc` is a handy tool.

Comment: The [Shift F12](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/etc/inputrc#L44)  one requires [vi mode](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_102.html).

Answer (score 7):

What's happening is that FreeBSD and Linux use different shells by default. FreeBSD defaults to [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh), which had better interactive features than bash in the past (but bash has caught up) but [markedly worse scripting features](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

The most straightforward way to get the environment you're used to would be to switch your shell to tcsh on Linux. Provided that tcsh is installed system-wide (if it isn't, ask your system administrator to install it), run `chsh -s tcsh` to change your default shell.

Alternatively, you can set up bash to have this command you're used to. By default, the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrows navigate among all the commands in the history, not just the ones that start with the prefix you've typed. To change this to the behavior you're used to, put the following lines in bash's initialization file, which is `.bashrc` in your home directory. Either run `. ~/.bashrc` or start a new shell to re-read the initialization file.

```
bind '"\eOA": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\eOB": history-search-forward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

The escape sequences are what your terminal sends to the shell when you press an arrow key. <kbd>Up</kbd> may be `\eOA` (escape, `O`, `A`) or `\e[A` depending on your terminal, and similarly for <kbd>Down</kbd>.

By default, bash offers different key bindings to search the command history. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then enter some characters to search for a command containing this substring anywhere on the line. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to go forward instead of backward. The search is incremental (i.e. as-you-type); <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> give you a non-incremental search.

Instead of bash and tcsh, you could switch to zsh, which [has some neat features not found in other shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/983/what-features-are-in-zsh-and-missing-from-bash-or-vice-versa/985#985). Zsh has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> by default just like bash. To get <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> like you had in tcsh, put the following lines in `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '\eOA' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\eOB' history-beginning-search-forward
bindkey '\e[B' history-beginning-search-forward
```

If you'd like to use the same shell everywhere, you can use bash or zsh on FreeBSD too, provided that the port is installed (again, ask your system administrator).

Answer (score 1):

`tcsh` is available for most Linux distributions.  Try installing the `tcsh` package, then running `chsh -s /bin/tcsh` to make it your default shell.

Comment: Or you might consider switching to bash (I did).