# Which is the real PATH variable

Tags: path, csh

On my office computer it seems like I've have two `PATH` variables.

> $path : This is delimited by " " (Space)
>
> $PATH : This is delimited by ":" (Colon)

Though when I update one, the other one gets updated as well. Is this the normal behavior in Linux or is there something weird going on in my machine?

Should I keep them both, or delete one of them?

**Edit:** I'm using `csh`, I found this because some of my colleagues were updating the "path" variable, while others did it with `PATH`. Though I deleted all occurrences of updating `PATH` in my `.cshrc`, it still appears when I try to echo them.

Comment: do NOT use csh... really. Too many bugs to list them all, and sometimes very weird behaviors as well. See for example: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ or http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-0 or http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt ... switch to a bourne-compatible shell (bash is nice, zsh even better but less present on some older platforms.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real `PATH` variable is the uppercase one, except in (t)csh itself where it's a little more complicated.

`PATH` is an environment variable, which all applications (not just shell) look up to invoke a program by name. The value of `PATH` is a string listing directory names separated by colons.

As a convenience, csh also provides a variable called `path`. The value of this variable is a list of strings, each string being a directory name. Whenever you set `path`, csh automatically sets `PATH` to the concatenation of the elements of `path` with `:` between elements.

If you set `PATH` with `set`, `path` is unaffected. Furthermore, csh set the `PATH` environment variable to match its `path` internal variable, so `set PATH=...` has no practical effect.

If you set `PATH` with `setenv`, `path` is updated accordingly. However `setenv PATH …` does not affect what `$PATH` expands to, which makes it awkward to use.

The upshot is that in csh, you should stick with `path`. But everywhere else `PATH` is the only one you'll see.

Comment: I should probably switch to BASH :D

Comment: @KartikAnand [zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/983/what-features-are-in-zsh-and-missing-from-bash-or-vice-versa/985#985)! (Which also has both `path` and `PATH`, but there it's less confusing because there isn't the shell/environment variable (`set`/`setenv`) distinction: in zsh, if you set `PATH` in any way, `path` is updated and vice versa.)

Comment: will sure do!! Anyways why doesn't zsh need both environment and shell variables? I thought that was necessary.

Comment: @KartikAnand In Bourne-style shells (sh, ash, bash, ksh, zsh, …), environment variables are automatically shell variables with the same value. A shell variable is either exported (in which case it's also an environment variable, with the same value), or not (in which case there is no environment variable by the same name). This simplifies matters somewhat.