# Undefined variable

Tags: scripting, csh

I am trying to use this script:

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach SUB (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
    echo $SUB
    foreach VISIT (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
        echo $VISIT
        grep 'StudyDate' -f  /home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI/D${SUB}/D${SUB}V${VIS}/scout/001/infodump.dat
    done
done
```

but every time I receive this error message:

```
1
1
SUB: Undefined variable.
```

and I don't know why.

Comment: do NOT use csh... really. Too many bugs to list them all, and sometimes very weird behaviors as well. See for example: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ or http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-0 or http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt ... switch to a bourne-compatible shell (bash is nice, zsh even better but less present on some older platforms.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from [all the reasons scripts shouldn't be written in `csh`](http://web.mit.edu/daveg/Info/csh.whynot), you are mixing bash syntax and csh syntax in your script.

You're starting your loop with the `csh` `foreach` and trying to finish them with the `bash` `done`.   The loop exit for a `csh` `foreach` is `end`, not `done`.  Also, you have a variable `VISIT` that you are calling `$VIS` in your grep statement.

So you script would be syntactically correct in csh with:

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach SUB (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
    echo $SUB
    foreach VISIT (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
        echo $VISIT
        grep 'StudyDate' -f  /home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI/D${SUB}/D${SUB}V${VISIT}/scout/001/infodump.dat
    end
end
```

or in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for SUB in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14; do
    echo $SUB
    for VISIT in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do
        echo $VISIT
        grep 'StudyDate' -f  /home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI/D${SUB}/D${SUB}V${VISIT}/scout/001/infodump.dat
    done
done
```

---

**EDIT 2017/04/03**

Here's a version of the bash script that adds a test for the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

idf_pfx="/home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI"
idf_sfx="scout/001/infodump.dat"

for SUB in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14; do
    echo $SUB
    for VISIT in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do
        echo $VISIT
        idfile="${idf_pfx}/D${SUB}/D${SUB}V${VISIT}/${idf_sfx}"
        if [ -f "${idfile}" ]; then
            grep 'StudyDate' $idfile
        else
            echo "No studydate file: $idfile"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks But I still got some error massages and I am sure I have those files in the dir ;  1 1 grep: /home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI/D6/D6V1/scout/001/infodu‌​‌​mp.dat: No such file or directory and when I was trying to use the second script I got this error massage ; ./test: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token do' ./test: line 4: foreach VISIT in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do

Comment: Apologies, @ManalOs, I left a `foreach` in the bash example.  I have removed it.
The other error about no such file or directory, is because the path the script is building isn't leading to a file.  You need to check the variable expansions in the file path, and make sure you're not missing a slash or something.   Or maybe that file just doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Tim again, what is the best way to check the file if it exist or not ? I still having the same error massages !                                                       grep: f-infodump.dat: No such file or directory
grep: /home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI/D14/D14V8/scout/001: Is a directory

Comment: in bash, you can test the existence of a file with a simple `if [ -f $file ]; then` test.  I've added an example for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I still had an error massage called ; No studydate file: /home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI/D14/D14V8/scout/001/infodump.dat . However, just to make sure that you are understand what I doing here . I am looking to find this word (studydate)  under file name called (f-infodump.dat) at this dir ;/home/colourlab/Desktop/DrummingDTI/D1/D1V1/scout/001 , and I am still don't know where is the mistake !

Comment: That's not an error.  That's an informational note supplied by the script above, in this line: `echo "No studydate file: $idfile"`.  The mistake is that you original example had the filename `infodump.dat`, not `f-infodump.dat`, so all of my examples have done the same.  Edit the script to look for the right filename and you'll have a better outcome.

Comment: I got this massage ;( grep: Invalid back reference) ! and thanks for trying help me to do this

Comment: ah, yeah.  your grep syntax was off.  `grep -f <file>` would mean that you're searching for the patterns that are enumerated in `<file>`.  Which is not what you want here.  Take the `-f` out of the grep, and your results should be more like what you actually want.

Comment: Another reason to not use `csh`:  [fun with $PATH. Wait. Or is that $path?!?!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118183/which-is-the-real-path-variable)  Note in the answer there that `$path` in `csh` is space-delimited.  I have never tested what happens if a directory with a space in its name is put into `csh`'s `$path`...

Answer (score 0):

Your error message does not match the code that you are showing. $SUB is a well defined variable and csh will not crib about it. Rather csh will emit the error "done: command not found" which you should have got. Are you sure you copy-pasted the correct message?

Comment: yes you alright I got this ; 1
1
SUB: Undefined variable.