# migrating zsh_history to .bash_history

Tags: bash, osx, zsh, command-history

I migrated from mac to linux

I backed up my `zsh_history.txt`

How can i merge/append it to my `.bash_history` file?

I see the format is different:

```
git pull
#1530441990
git push
#1530447814
locate "*ls*" | grep -P 'history'
#1530447865
echo  $HISTFILE
#1530448256



: 1470922871:0;git clone
: 1470923028:0;git clone sso://waze-bimqa-internal/RoutingRegression
: 1470924442:0;ls -ltrh `echo $JAVA_HOME`
: 1470924459:0;java -v
: 1470924464:0;which java
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not keep using zsh? If you're used to zsh, [going back to bash is a recipe for disappointment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/983/what-features-are-in-zsh-and-missing-from-bash-or-vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the timestamps, you could use the `history -s` command to add lines to the `bash` history.

```
bash-4.2$ history -s foo
bash-4.2$ history -s this is a command
bash-4.2$ history 3
   31  foo
   32  this is a command
   33  history 3
```

You can manipulate your text file to generate the `history -s` commands and then `source` it.